# Using a Scanner and String as input for method

Tags: java, methods

Hey I have been stuck on this issue for a while but I'm trying to fit in a String and a Scanner in a method like this:

```
void top (String coordinates, Scanner top) {

        while (top.hasNext()){
            coordinates(new Scanner(top.next()));
            System.out.println(coordinates);
        }
```

the error does not occur in this part but in this one:

```
void start() {
        Scanner in = UIAuxiliaryMethods.askUserForInput().getScanner();
        in.useDelimiter("=");

        top(new Scanner(in.next()));

        while (in.hasNext()){
            behind(new Scanner(in.next()));
            infront(new Scanner(in.next()));
        }
    }
```

It says it not applicable for the arguements (Scanner). I did make two Strings but then I can not use in.hasNext() nor next(). Someone knows how were the error lies? If this is not possible I guess I do have to make two Strings for the method and redo the void top.

Since I some thought there was not String passed I did make a Method for that but the Method only got used in the while loop of that Method itself.

```
String coordinates (Scanner coordinates) {
        coordinates.useDelimiter(",");

        int arr[] = new int[2];
        int k;

        for(int j=-1;coordinates.hasNextInt();j++) {
            if (j/2!=0) {
                k = coordinates.nextInt()+1;
            } else {
                k = coordinates.nextInt();
            }
            arr[j] = k;
        } 
        String str = arr[1]+","+arr[2];
        return str;
    }
```

(It does look not nice at all but I have to something with an Array for the assignment)

Eclipse says to do it like this

```js
top(null, new Scanner(in.next()));
```

The error in the system goes away but when I run it throws:
java.lang.NullPointerException

Comment: Why do you keep creating new scanners?

Comment: I think it's easy to work with and they though us this in class

Comment: Try using an IDE like eclipse.  A lot of this code should be throwing compile errors.

Comment: "I think it's easy to work with" And yet here we are...

Comment: Well I thought so till now @AndyTurner haha

Comment: @Joe I'm using eclipse

Answer (score 1):

You can't call

```
top(new Scanner(in.next()));
```

because the `top` method needs a `String` and a `Scanner`:

```
void top (String coordinates, Scanner top) {
```

You are only passing in a single argument, a `Scanner`.

Pass in the `String` as well, first.

Comment: Can I not call a Method in Method? Because I did work the String coordinates out which works fine. But I made it kinda complex because in the while loop I made the command to use that Method (for the first time).

Comment: Of course you can call a method in a method. But you have to call it with the right number and type of parameters.